# Unresolved external symbols since Visual Studio 2015 update 3: boost python linking error if destructor is virtual

Tags: visual-studio, boost

We are getting strange unresolved symbols linking errors since we updated to Visual Studio 2015 update 3. Anyone else encountered the same kind of issues ?

What is really weird is that boost::get_pointer is a template method, defined in a boost header. I do not understand how we can get an undefined external symbol in that case :(.

Here is a reproducer, with boost 1.61 and Python 3.5.1:

```
#include <vector>
#include <boost/python.hpp>

using namespace boost::python;

class Canard {
public:
    Canard() {}
    virtual ~Canard() {}
};

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(coin)
{
     register_ptr_to_python< std::shared_ptr<Canard> >();
}
```

And the error:

```
 Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "class Canard const volatile * __cdecl boost::get_pointer<class Canard const volatile >(class Canard const volatile *)" (??$get_pointer@$$CDVCanard@@@boost@@YAPEDVCanard@@PEDV1@@Z) referenced in function "private: static struct _typeobject * __cdecl boost::python::objects::make_ptr_instance<class Canard,struct boost::python::objects::pointer_holder<class std::shared_ptr<class Canard>,class Canard> >::get_derived_class_object<class Canard>(struct boost::mpl::bool_<1>,class Canard const volatile *)" (??$get_derived_class_object@VCanard@@@?$make_ptr_instance@VCanard@@U?$pointer_holder@V?$shared_ptr@VCanard@@@std@@VCanard@@@objects@python@boost@@@objects@python@boost@@CAPEAU_typeobject@@U?$bool_@$00@mpl@3@PEDVCanard@@@Z)   CCMasterKernelPyPy  C:\work\dev\builds\internal\Master\SDK\MasterKernelPyPy\main.obj    1
```

But as soon as I remove the virtual in front of the destructor of the Canard class, then it starts working.... Does anyone have a clue ? Is it a Visual Studio bug ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Visual Studio 2015 update 3 has added lots of features and improvements (see the release notes https://www.visualstudio.com/news/releasenotes/vs2015-update3-vs#visualcpp).
It also have some known issues (https://msdn.microsoft.com/vs-knownissues/vs2015-update3 see the Passing non-pointer-like types to uninitialized_copy section).

To fix your problem you need to explicitly specify the conversion to pointer of your class, explicitly:

```
namespace boost
{
    template <>
    Canard const volatile * get_pointer<class Canard const volatile >(
      class Canard const volatile *c)
    {
        return c;
    }
}
```

Good luck, 
Ohad

Comment: A [bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Feedback/Details/2852624) has been filed for this issue in the Visual Studio bug tracker, and lists a workaround similar to the one Ohad suggested. You may want to keep track of the bug's status and comments in case a compiler fix is added in the next update to Visual Studio.

Comment: Thanks for the workaround. I couldn't make it work for abstract classes when there is an include to `boost/optional.hpp` because the `get_pointer` overload somehow tries to instantiate `boost::optional<volatile const Canard>`.

Do you know any other possible workaround for this case?

Comment: This also does not work for namespaced boost unfortunately. Has this been fixed in MSVC?